# Different buttons in view to perform different operation in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am facing some problem in MVC

Inside view I have 2 buttons, one is for final submit and the other is for adding dynamic content to the view. Again both are used to post the form. I wanted to know how these would be used in controller.

**example**

If I click final submit, it will redirect to some view or any other operation and also if I click add button in the same view I want to return to the same view.

**note**: I am using both buttons to post the same action.

Comment: why you use same action? I think separate action is better

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="submit" name="actionBtn" value="add value" />
<input type="submit" name="actionBtn" value="finalsubmit" />
```

in Action

```
public ActionResult YourPostAction(string actionBtn)
{
   if(actionBtn == "Add Value")
  {
  }
  else if(actionBtn == "finalSubmit")
  {
  }
}
```

Another way if you want ( You have to play with name but different way)

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <input type="hidden" name="actionName" id="hdnAction" />
    <input type="submit" value="test" name="actionBtn" onclick="setThis('test')" />
    <input type="submit" value="test1" name="actionBtn" onclick="setThis('test1')"/>
}

<script language="javascript">
    function setThis(obj) {            
        document.getElementById('hdnAction').value = obj;
    }
</script>
```

In controller action

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(string actionName)
        {
          ViewBag.Message = "Modify this template to jump-start your ASP.NET MVC application.";    
          return View();
        }
```

Comment: I have already used same approach but this is not good idea bcoz we are using string to find button it is very difficult to maintain application if any spell mastake between string value developer would face difficulties explore any different approach

Comment: Spell problem is another issue and to overcome that issue you can either use constant or use resource file. Later compare value with constant it self.